Using across function in R
I have a database similar to this one:
data <- tibble(X = c(1,2,3,4), X_2 = c(2,3,4,5),
               Y = c(3,4,5,6), Y_2 = c(4,5,6,7))


I would like to mutate across X and Y so I could sum X with X_2 and Y with Y_2, generating new vars called X_3 and Y_3.
I was trying with something like this:
data %>% 
  mutate(across(c(X,Y), ~ . + ._2 , .names = "{col}_3")) %>% 
  print()

or like this:
data %>% 
  mutate(across(c(X,Y), ~ . + paste0(.,"_2") , .names = "{col}_3")) %>% 
  print()

Obviously neither of those work since I don't know how to define the second variable that has the same name as the one that I use in the across function (but ends with a suffix).
Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

To achieve this using across, you can use the cur_column() function within across to dynamically reference the column names. Here's how you can do it:
Use mutate and across to create the new variables:
result <- data %>% 
    mutate(across(c(X, Y), 
    ~ . + get(paste0(cur_column(), "_2")), 
    .names = "{col}_3"))


Welcome to SO!  That's a good first answer, but it would be even better if you showed the result on running your code on OP's test data: that would provide evidence that it is correct.
